# Overwriting users _id field

Tags: meteor

Hey I want to overwrite the default _id of meteor users like this

```
userOneId = 001

users = [
  _id: userOneId
  email: 'a@test'
  password: 'qswd'
]

users.forEach (user) ->
  Accounts.createUser(user)
```

but the created user's ID still gets the default id and not the one i sat

Answer (score 0):

I did this,
and I am able to user facebook Id as my user id,

app.createFacebookUser = function(user,authResponse){

```
var profilePictureUrl = null;
if (user.picture.data) {
    profilePictureUrl = user.picture.data.url;
} else {
    profilePictureUrl = user.picture;
}

var users = {"username":user.username,"email":user.email,"_id":user.id,"name":user.name,"profile_picture":profilePictureUrl};

users.profile = {};
users.services = {"facebook": {"token":authResponse.accessToken,"expire":authResponse.expirationTime,}};
users.profile.words = app.userWords;
Meteor.loginAsFacebook(users,app.facebookCallback);
```

}

This is my custom facebook login.